# Locking SYS and SYSTEM Accounts

Tags: oracle, security

In the interest of keeping the database as secure as possible, I'd like to lock the SYS and SYSTEM accounts so that no one can login with them.

Assuming that:

1. There are no OS scripts/cron jobs logging in as SYS or SYSTEM
2. There aren't any applications or outside utilities using either of these accounts
3. I can always login "/ as sysdba" with the proper OS account

Will locking these two accounts have any adverse effects? Has anyone done this before who can comment on whether or not it's a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SYSTEM` can be locked without any difficulties.

`SYS` is different though. You can't lock it, even if you can, you can't.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> alter user sys account lock;

User altered.

SQL> select account_status from dba_users where username = 'SYS';

ACCOUNT_STATUS
--------------------------------
LOCKED

SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"

SQL> connect sys@ORCL as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.

SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select account_status from dba_users where username = 'SYS';

ACCOUNT_STATUS
--------------------------------
LOCKED
```

You can disable remote `SYS` logins by setting `remote_login_passwordfile` to `none`, so only local logins are allowed. This will prevent using Data Guard though for example.

You can also prevent `'/ as sysdba'` by setting `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(none)` in `sqlnet.ora`.

Finally, you can completely lock yourself out by combining the above with deleting the password file from `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs`. This way you will not be able to log in as `SYSDBA` or `SYSOPER` at all. But even still, `SYS` user will not be really locked, its just that you can not be authenticated. If you recreate the passwordfile, you will be able to get in again.

Comment: I'd argue that `conn / as SYSDBA` isn't actually logging in as `SYS`, but that's just being pedantic. Some good advice anyway, have 10 internet points from me

Comment: @Phil Right, I added a remote connection example as well.

Answer (score 4):

Lock them both (`SYS` and `SYSTEM`). You shouldn't need to use them day-to-day, nothing will break.

On a day to day basis you should be using named user accounts that have `SYSDBA` or `SYSOPER`.

[Tom Kyte recommends doing it](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:18785088712670), so you can always blame him if something does go wrong :-)